# Not between in scala spark

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I am able to use

```
df1.filter(col("numberic1").between(lower_bound, upper_bound))).count
```

but

```
df1.filter(col("numberic1").not(between(lower_bound, upper_bound)))).count
```

does not work

How can one achieve not between functionality in scala spark ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `!` operator i.e. `df1.filter(!col("numberic1").between(lower_bound, upper_bound))).count` should serve your purpose.

Answer (score 2):

Not between means less than lower_bound or greater than upper_bound. 
So if `not(between(...))` does not work, you can always do:

```
df1.filter(col("numberic1").lt(lower_bound) || col("numberic1").gt(upper_bound)).count
```